# Android and reordering the children of a ViewGroup

Tags: android, layout, parent-child, viewgroup

1. How do you exchange the indices of two children in a ViewGroup?
2. How do I use `setLeft` on a child view? It doesn't seem to be defined for objects of class `View`.

Edit.

Answer to #2 is that `setLeft` is only available from API11. Ditto `setX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all children and than add by required order. I'm not found another way.

IMHO the best way for reorganize layout is use RelativeLayout.

As I do this:

```
// prepare rules
lpTopLeft = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(minDimension/5, minDimension/5);
lpTopLeft.setMargins(minDimension/50, minDimension/50, minDimension/50, minDimension/50);
lpTopLeft.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
lpTopLeft.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
```

And now use prepared settings:

```
// rearrange child
bnReset.setLayoutParams(lpTopLeft);
```

Comment: Indeed. I'd like to rearrange the children without having to inflate the entire layout from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I guess removing the views and re-inflating the layout is the only solution. Maybe you can try to use a [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). I don't know if it's suitable for your case.

Answer (score 1):

best solution:
[flexbox-layout by Google](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

FexboxLayout is a library project which brings the similar capabilities of CSS Flexible Box Layout Module to Android.

Then you can set

> layout_order

This attribute can change how the ordering of the children views are laid out. By default, children are displayed and laid out in the same order as they appear in the layout XML. If not specified, 1 is set as a default value.